# Where can I find statistics on security breaches?

Tags: research, statistics

I am putting together a security presentation, and I would like statistics on the occurrence of and damages from security breaches. Does anyone know of a reliable, recently-updated source?

Comment: See also http://security.stackexchange.com/q/12041/836 which asks for statistics that were particular to MITM attacks.

Comment: You'll probably find the Symantec threat report helpful: http://www.symantec.com/threatreport/

Comment: @makerofthings7 The Symantec report is clear, well-organized and didn't require me to register for anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Likely helpful:

[Verizon's Data Breach Investigations Reports](http://www.verizonbusiness.com/Products/security/dbir/?CMP=DMC-SMB_Z_ZZ_ZZ_Z_TV_N_Z041)
[Trustwave's Global Security Reports](https://www.trustwave.com/global-security-report?utm_expid=5000628-0)
[Mandiant's M-Trends](http://www.mandiant.com/resources/m-trends/)

Answer (score 4):

### **Key List of Resources (2015)**

---

- **Industry Forecast**

  - [Data Breach Industry Forecast by Experian](http://www.experian.com/assets/data-breach/white-papers/2015-industry-forecast-experian.pdf?_ga=1.172114915.1943093614.1418003182)
- **Industry Survey**

  - [Global Industry Information Security Survey by PWC](http://www.pwc.com/gx/en/consulting-services/information-security-survey/)
  - [Security Personnel Survey by Kaspersky](http://media.kaspersky.com/en/business-security/Global-IT-Risks-Report-2014-Threat-Security-Data-Breaches.pdf?icid=en-GL:ent-carousel)
- **Statistics & Reports**

  - [Data Breach Statistics by IBM](http://www-935.ibm.com/services/us/en/it-services/security-services/data-breach/)
  - [Data Breach Investigation Reports](http://www.verizonenterprise.com/resources/reports/rp_data-breach-investigation-report-2015_en_xg.pdf) [by Verizon](http://www.verizonenterprise.com/DBIR/)
  - [Data Breach Statistics and summary by ITRC](http://www.idtheftcenter.org/ITRC-Surveys-Studies/2015databreaches.html)
  - [Security Report by Cisco with industry-sorted statistics](http://www.cisco.com/web/offer/gist_ty2_asset/Cisco_2015_ASR.pdf)
  - [Application and Network Security Report by Radware](http://www.radware.com/ert-report-2014/)
  - [Internet Security Statistics by Symantec](http://know.symantec.com/LP=1233)
  - [Infrastructure Security Report](http://www.arbornetworks.com/resources/infrastructure-security-report) [by Arbor](http://www.arbornetworks.com/)
  - [Security Intelligence Report by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44937)
- **Resource Hub**

  - [White Papers, Incident Response, Daily Updates - from DataBreachToday](http://www.databreachtoday.com)
  - [More links to resources by Zdnet](http://www.zdnet.com/article/cybersecurity-in-2015-what-to-expect/)
  - [State of the Internet by Akamai](http://www.stateoftheinternet.com/)
  - [More links by Network World](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2868018/cisco-subnet/annual-security-reports-predict-what-we-can-expect-in-2015.html)
- **Infograph**

  - [Cybersecurity](https://www.lumension.com/Lumension/media/graphics/Resources/2015-state-of-the-endpoint/2015-State-of-the-Endpoint-InfoGraphic-Lumension.pdf)  [by Lumension](https://www.lumension.com/2015)

Answer (score 3):

http://datalossdb.org/statistics - truly opensource and not marketing-driven data.

Comment: The sources they get the data from (state governments) are open, but one must request permission to use their compiled data and charts. Too bat it's not under a Creative Commons license.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to this as I check for relevancy.

- **FireEye + Mandiant**

  - [Advanced Threat Report](https://www2.fireeye.com/WEB-2015RPTM-Trends.html) (2015): [key findings](https://www.fireeye.com/company/press-releases/2015/02/fireeye-releases-annual-mandiant-threat-report-highlighting-insi.html) (press release)
- **CrowdStrike**

  - [Global Threat Intel Report](http://blog.crowdstrike.com/crowdstrikes-2014-global-threat-report-know-adversary-better-protect-network/) (Feb-2015). Numbers are sparse but charts are estimable.
  - Intelligence reports and data in the [adversary lineup](http://blog.crowdstrike.com/category/the-adversary-line-up/) section of the site are over these [adversaries and target industries](http://blog.crowdstrike.com/meet-the-adversaries/).
- **Palo Alto Networks**

  - [Data breach frequency article](http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2015/03/data-breach-frequency-doesnt-slow-cloud-computing-momentum/) links to Identity Theft Resource Center [Data Breach Reports](http://www.idtheftcenter.org/images/breach/DataBreachReports_2015.pdf) (2015)
- **Krebs on Security**

  - An [entire section of articles](http://krebsonsecurity.com/category/data-breaches/) on data breaches.
- **DataLossDB**

  - [Charts](http://datalossdb.org/statistics) with basic adjustment. Broken down by a few categories such as incidents, business types, data type. May require licensing.
- **Breach Level Index**

  - [Home tab](http://www.breachlevelindex.com/) has mass statistics, recency and global scope with useful search at the database tab.
- **Infographics**

  - [Top 5 Most Compromised](http://info.rippleshot.com/blog/rippleshot-research-the-top-five-most-compromised-mccs) Merchant Categories with summary spend

Answer (score 0):

I did a presentation on the exact same thing last year. I found [Zone-H.org](http://www.zone-h.org/) to be a good source.

Edit: Sign up for an account to view most of the pages. (Registration is free)