# How to Trust a Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: trust, self-signed

According to [Why are self signed certificates not trusted and is there a way to make them trusted?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112768/why-are-self-signed-certificates-not-trusted-and-is-there-a-way-to-make-them-tru), to trust a self-signed certificate we need to import the root certificate into the trust store of the browser. Does that mean I must distribute to my clients a file, and is that the *.crt file, the *.csr, or the *.key file? What instructions should they follow to import that certificate correctly?

Answer (score 5):

> Does that mean I must distribute to my clients a file, and is that the *.crt file, the *.csr, or the *.key file?

You need to distribute the certificate, i.e. the `*.crt` file. The `*.key` file must be kept secret since this can be used to impersonate the certificate. It is only actually needed on the server.

> What instructions should they follow to import that certificate correctly?

There is no generic way to install a certificate. Details depend on OS and client (i.e. different browsers, apps ...).

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean I must distribute to my clients a file, and is that the *.crt file, the *.csr, or the *.key file?

Both self-signed and CA-signed certificates share certain characteristics - they both have a private key that must be kept secret and a signed certificate that contains public key that you share with others. They key difference between CA-signed and self-signed certificates is what key is used to sign the certificate - self-signed certificate uses the private key associated with the certificate to sign it. To make all of this a bit more confusing, Root CAs are also self-signed, to differentiate them from a regular self-signed certificate you need to look at extensions like Basic Constraints.